# Using Axios Interceptors Causing axios.get is not a function Error

Tags: node.js, axios, interceptor

I have a node js project in which I am trying to use axios, and am using an axios interceptor to set the baseURL. The problem is that everytime I try to call axios.get, it throws the error "axios.get is not a function". It works if I do not use an interceptor.

In the lib folder of my project I have a file called axios.js:

```
const axios = require('axios');

const isAbsoluteURLRegex = /^(?:\w+:)\/\//;

axios.interceptors.request.use(function(config) {
  if ( !isAbsoluteURLRegex.test(config.url) ) {
    config.url = `https:localhost:1234${config.url}`;
  }

  return config;
});
```

Then, in the file where I want to use axios I have:

```
const axios = require('../lib/axios')
....
const response = await axios.get(`/api/report/8`)
```

But when it calls axios.get the error is thrown.

It works if I intsead use:

```
const axios = require('axios')
....
const response = await axios.get(`https:localhost:1234/api/report/8`)
```

But as there will be multiple calls using the base URL, as well as some auth0 stuff I want to throw in I need to get it to use the interceptor.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? I'm using axios 1.1.3.